# how to initializeUnorderedBulkOp()?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

New to `MongoDB`, I am trying to optimize bulk writes to the database. I do not understand how to initialize the `Bulk()` operations, though.

My understanding is that since the inserts will be done on a collection, this is where (or rather "on what") `initializeUnorderedBulkOp()` should be initialized:

The code below covers all the cases I can think of:

```
import pymongo

conn = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb.example.com', 27017)
db = conn.test
coll = db.testing

# tried all of the following
# this one does not make much sense to me as I insert to a collection, added for completeness
bulk = db.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
# that one seems to be the most reasonable to me   
bulk = coll.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
# that one is from http://blog.mongodb.org/post/84922794768/mongodbs-new-bulk-api   
bulk = db.collection('testing').initializeUnorderedBulkOp()

# the staging and execution
# bulk.find({'name': 'hello'}).update({'name': 'hello', 'who': 'world'})
# bulk.execute()
```

The exception raised is

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'initializeUnorderedBulkOp' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

with `'Database'` for the first case and `'Collection'` for the last two

How should I use `initializeUnorderedBulkOp()` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Python (using the `pymongo` module), the method name is not `initializeUnorderedBulkOp` but `initialize_unordered_bulk_op`.

You have to call it, as you correctly guessed, on the collection (in your case, `coll.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()` should work).

Comment: This function has been deprecated in 4.0 https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrate-to-pymongo4.html#id39

Comment: What function should be used instead? of initialize_unordered_bulk_op()? @Darshan